# trying to get array back to list in a table

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Jquery - I am getting undefined but in the php is giving the response with my table information.

```
function formfill(dblist) {
    var tableheader = "<thead><tr><th>Database Nick</th><th>Database IP</th> <th></th></tr></thead>";

    $('#table2').empty();
    $('#table2').append(tableheader);

    $.each(dblist, function (key, value) {
        $('#table2').append('<tr><td>' 
        + dblist['DBNick'] 
        + '</td><td>' 
        + dblist['DBIP'] 
        + '</td><td><input class="add" id="add" name="add" value="add" type="submit"></input></td></tr>');

    }); 
}

$('#userlist').on('change', function () {
    var selected = $('#userlist').val();

    console.log(selected);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/php/user/userdbtable.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { user: selected },
        success: function (data) {
            formfill(data)
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, err) { console.log(xhr, status, err); }
    });
});
```

Here is the php it is sending out the correct data but i cant figure out how to pull it from the object.

```
<?php 
session_start(); 

include '../connect/anonconnect.php'; 

$myusername= $_POST['user'];

$useridsql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserLogin= :login");
$useridsql->execute(array(':login' => $myusername));
$useridsql = $useridsql->fetch();

$userid = $useridsql['idUser'];

$query = 'SELECT * FROM DBList  INNER JOIN UserDBList 
    ON DBList.idDatabase = UserDBList.idDatabase ';//WHERE UserDBList.idUser = '.$userid; 
$sql = $dbh->prepare($query); 
$sql->bindParam(':username', $myusername, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12); 
$sql->execute(); 
$user = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

if($sql->rowCount() == 1){ 
    header('Content-type: application/json'); 
    echo json_encode($user,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); 
} 
else { 
    echo 0; 
}   
?>
```

Comment: Post the JSON object as returned from PHP as well.

Comment: are we to assume that #userlist is a select?

Comment: Yes userlist is the name and id of a dropdown menu

Comment: And the jquery does fire on the dropdown but the data it is adding to the table is "undefined" except the button, the button is fine lol

Comment: What do `console.log(data)` and `console.log(typeof(data))` show within your `success` handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your loop has an error.  It should look like this:

```
$.each(dblist, function (index, item) {
    $('#table2').append('<tr><td>' 
        + item['DBNick'] 
        + '</td><td>' 
        + item['DBIP'] 
        + '</td><td><input class="add" id="add" name="add" value="add" type="submit"></input></td></tr>');

});
```

Comment: Looks right, although `value` and `item` are going to be the same, so `item` is redundant.

Comment: @PaulRoub - You are right...edited my answer to remove redundancy.  Thanks